# getTag() always null in onListItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I have a `ListView` that I'm populating with a `CursorAdapter` like this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder viewBinder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(MyTableColumns._ID))
        {
            view.setTag(cursor.getInt(columnIndex));
        }
        // some other stuff
    }
};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_item_renderer, cursor, from, to);
adapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
```

The aim is to get the ID from the list item clicked:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Object obj = v.getTag();
    int myId = Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
}
```

However this is always returning `null`. What am I overlooking? For now I'm just using a hidden text field but I'd like to know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onListItemClick()` provides you with a view that is the row in the list. `ViewBinder` binds values to the TextViews inside this row. Thus the view you call `setTag()` on is not the same as the view you call `getTag()` on.

You can either extend SimpleCursorAdapter so you can call `setTag()` on the correct view, or you can get the first child view of `v` in `onListItemClick()` and get the tag of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this when setting your tag?

```
view.setTag(new Integer(cursor.getInt(columnIndex)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your "if" statement simply returns false and thus no Tag value gets set?

Comment: good point but I just didn't include that in the code snippet here, I am returning true in the actual project.